# Why is this considered a type mismatch (or error)?

Tags: function, haskell, types, type-declaration

This is the code I have which results in the error that follows:

```
import Prelude hiding (div)

data Expr = Expr Op Int Int deriving (Show)
data Op = Add | Sub | Mul | Div deriving (Show)


evaluate :: (Num a) => Expr -> a
evaluate (Expr Add a b) = a + b
--evaluate (Expr Sub a b) = sub a b
--evaluate (Expr Mul a b) = mul a b
--evaluate (Expr Div a b) = div a b
```

Error message:

```
    exprs.hs:8:27: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Int’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          evaluate :: forall a. Num a => Expr -> a
        at exprs.hs:7:1-32
    • In the expression: a + b
      In an equation for ‘evaluate’: evaluate (Expr Add a b) = a + b
    • Relevant bindings include
        evaluate :: Expr -> a (bound at exprs.hs:8:1)
  |
8 | evaluate (Expr Add a b) = a + b
  |                           ^^^^^
Failed, 0 modules loaded.
```

However, the (+) function has type `(Num a) => a -> a -> a`, and
the pattern I'm matching in the function `evaluate` has two *Ints* (a & b) which are **both part of the Num typeclass**. Since the result of calling (+) on a & b will be of type Int (from the Num typeclass) and that is also what I'm declaring the type of the output of my `evaluate` function to be, why is GHCi giving me this error?

Note that, if I change the type declaration of `evaluate` to

```
evaluate :: Expr -> Int
```

then this error does not come up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
evaluate :: (Num a) => Expr -> a
```

states that for *any* type `a` which has a `Num` instance, `evaluate` can return a value of type `a` given an `Expr` value. However given the definition of `Expr`, you can only ever return an `Int`, and the compiler is therefore rejecting your definition.

If it were allowed you would be able to do:

```
evaluate (Expr Add 2 3) :: Double
```

which your definition cannot satisfy.

You can use your definition if you allow `Expr` to be parameterised by the expression type:

```
data Expr a = Expr Op a a deriving (Show)

evaluate :: (Num a) => Expr a -> a
evaluate (Expr Add a b) = a + b
...
```

Comment: So, specifically the data constructor Expr Op Int Int could only ever have two Ints, which in turn means that (+) in the function definition will always return an Int, so it doesn't match the type declaration... Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: @corecase - Yes that's right - the caller gets to choose the type `a`, not your implementation so you can't make any assumptions about it.

Comment: @corecase That type promises that whoever calls `evaluate` can choose the numeric return type (e.g. a `Double`). So, `evaluate` must adapt to any such choice, and can not just cover the `Int` case.